# HTML selection type

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem with my selection type.. 
IF select **WAPC** the **yeargrad** selection type should contain the year 2011-2015, ASU the the yeargrad should be 2000-2010, INAIS 1900-1999..

```
<div class="field">
<label for="school">School</label>
<select name="school" id="school" >                                                                                         <option value="WAPC" selected>WAPC</option>
<option value="INAIS">INAIS</option>
<option value="ASU">ASU</option>
</select>                       
</div>  



<select name="yeargrad" id="yeargrad">
<?php           
if(['school'] == 'WAPC'){                               
for ($i=2011; $i<=2015; $i++)
{
echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
} 
}

if(['school'] == 'ASU'){                                
for ($i=2000; $i<=2010; $i++)
{
echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
} 
}

if(['school'] == 'WAPC'){                               
for ($i=1999; $i<=1990; $i++)
{
echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
} 
}
?>
?>  
</select>
```

Comment: `['school']` <- This doesn't work I think you want to wrap your select in a form and use the matching superglobal (e.g. `$_GET` , `$_POST`) `?>
?>` doulbe closing tags? Remove one

Comment: this is more like pseudo code waiting to be a working one, (no form tags, no indication if POST or GET, etc.)

Comment: i think js should be best here

Comment: the school is selection type that contains 'WAPC', 'INAIS', 'ASU'..

Comment: if i select WAPC.. under the year graduated which is a selection box should contains range between 2011-2015, ASU betwenn 1990-2014

Comment: The issue here is ['school'] is not a PHP variable.  it looks like you might be referencing an index of array... but it is unclear what ['school'] should be or is.  should this be $school... even that does not make sense... I agree JavaScript would probably make more sense here.

Comment: php is a server side language. it seems that you are trying to execute php code based on the selected value in the first input. this cannot work because once the html is sent to the user, there is no more php. you have to use javascript to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in JS/JQUERY

This is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/2hx1o4ns/8/

Add onchange-Function to the Select-Element.

```
<div class="field">
<label for="school">School</label>
<select name="school" id="school" onchange="change()">
    <option value="WAPC" selected>WAPC</option>
    <option value="INAIS">INAIS</option>
    <option value="ASU">ASU</option>
</select>
</div>
  <select name="yeargrad" id="yeargrad">
</select>
```

And this in JS

```
function change(){
   var selectetOption = $('#school').find(":selected").text();

   if(selectetOption==='WAPC'){
       for (i = 2011; i <= 2015; i++) {
         $('#yeargrad').append("<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>");
       }
   }
   else if(...){
       ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use jquery is easier

This is my sample
https://jsfiddle.net/humpy6qL/15/

HTML:

```
<select name="select1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="val1">value 1</option>
  <option value="val2">value 2</option>
  <option value="val3">value 3</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
</select>
```

JQuery

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name="select1"]').on('change', function(){
        var sel1 = $(this);
      var sel2 = $('select[name="select2"]');
      $('option', sel2).remove();
      if(sel1.val() === 'val1'){//Checks the select value
        sel2.append(new Option("option text1", "value1"));
        sel2.append(new Option("option text2", "value2"));
      }
      else if(sel1.val() === 'val2'){
        sel2.append(new Option("option text3", "value3"));
        sel2.append(new Option("option text4", "value4"));
      }
      else if(sel1.val() === 'val3'){
        sel2.append(new Option("option text5", "value6"));
        sel2.append(new Option("option text6", "value7"));
      }
    });  
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help.

```
<select name="school" id="school" onchange="showHint(this.value);">
    <option value="WAPC" selected>WAPC</option>
    <option value="INAIS">INAIS</option>
    <option value="ASU">ASU</option>
</select>

<script>
    function showHint(str) {
        if (str.length == 0) {
            console.log("Value doesn't come");
            return;
        } else {
             var sel = document.getElementById('yeargrad');
             sel.innerHTML = null;
             if(str == 'WAPC'){
                 for (var i = 2011; i < 2016; i++) {
                     var opt = document.createElement('option');
                     opt.innerHTML = i;
                     opt.value = i;
                     sel.appendChild(opt);
                 }
             }elseif(str == 'INAIS'){
                 for (var i = 1900; i < 2000; i++) {
                     var opt = document.createElement('option');
                     opt.innerHTML = i;
                     opt.value = i;
                     sel.appendChild(opt);
                 }
             }elseif(str == 'ASU'){
                 for (var i = 2000; i < 2011; i++) {
                     var opt = document.createElement('option');
                     opt.innerHTML = i;
                     opt.value = i;
                     sel.appendChild(opt);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Let me know if this helped.